# Unable to differentiate between plane detected by ARKit and a digital object to be placed using HitTest

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm fairly new to iOS Swift programming. I'm using ARKit to build a very basic app to detect a horizontal plane and place,translate,rotate,modify or delete an object on it.

My main concern is to differential between the plane detected by ARKit and a digital object that I've placed. My thinking was to use hitTest(*:options:) to select the object (if any) and hitTest(*:types:) to select the plane through a tap gesture. I'm attaching the relevant code snippet below.

```
@objc func tapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let sceneView = gesture.view as! ARSCNView

    let location = gesture.location(in: sceneView)


    let hitTestOptions: [SCNHitTestOption: Any] = [.boundingBoxOnly: true]
    let existingNodeHitTest = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: hitTestOptions)

    if let existingNode = existingNodeHitTest.first?.node {

        // Move, rotate, modify or delete the object

    } else {

        // Option to add other objects

        let hitTest = sceneView.hitTest(location, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)

        if !hitTest.isEmpty {

            let node = findNode(at: location)

            if node !== selectedNode {

                self.addItems(hitTestResult: hitTest.first!)


            } 

        }

}

}

func addItems(hitTestResult: ARHitTestResult) {


        let scene = SCNScene(named: "BuildingModels.scnassets/model/model.scn")


        let itemNode = (scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "SketchUp", recursively: false))!


        let transform = hitTestResult.worldTransform
        let position = SCNVector3(transform.columns.3.x,transform.columns.3.y,transform.columns.3.z)
        itemNode.position = position
        //            self.sceneView.scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = scene.lightingEnvironment.contents

        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(itemNode)
        selectedNode = itemNode

}

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else {return}

    let gridNode = createGrid(planeAnchor: planeAnchor)
    node.addChildNode(gridNode)


}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else {return}

    node.enumerateChildNodes { (childNode, _) in
        childNode.removeFromParentNode()
    }

    let gridNode = createGrid(planeAnchor: planeAnchor)
    node.addChildNode(gridNode)

}
```

When I run the code, the hitTest(_:options:) returns the plane detected. Are there any ways to select only the SCNNodes (objects) that I place and not the plane detected. Am I missing something? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sourabh.

Comment: You can name nodes. `findNode` returns an array of nodes that pass the hit test - just iterate through (rather than using `.first`) until you find one with the name you gave it... (at least I think so - can't test at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question you are already half way there.

The way to handle this in it's entirety, is to make use of the following `HitTest` functions within your `UITapGestureRecognizer` function:

(1) An `ARSCNHitTest` which:

> Searches for real-world objects or AR anchors in the captured camera image corresponding to a point in the SceneKit view.

(2) An`SCNHitTest` which:

> Looks for SCNGeometry objects along the ray you specify. For each intersection between the ray and and a geometry, SceneKit creates a hit-test result to provide information about both the SCNNode object containing the geometry and the location of the intersection on the geometry’s surface.

Using your `UITapGestureRecognizer` as an example therefore, you can differentiate between an `ARPlaneAnchor` (detectedPlane) and any `SCNNode` within your scene like so:

```
@objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    //1. Get The Current Touch Location
    let currentTouchLocation = gesture.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView)

    //2. Perform An ARNSCNHitTest To See If We Have Hit An ARPlaneAnchor
    if let planeHitTest = augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchLocation, types: .existingPlane).first,
        let planeAnchor = planeHitTest.anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor{

        print("User Has Tapped On An Existing Plane = \(planeAnchor.identifier)")
        return
    }

    //3. Perform An SCNHitTest To See If We Have Hit An SCNNode
    if let nodeHitTest = augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchLocation, options: nil).first {

        let nodeTapped = nodeHitTest.node

        print("An SCNNode Has Been Tapped = \(nodeTapped)")
        return
    }

}
```

If you make use of the `name` property for any of your `SCNNode`’s this will also help you further e.g:

```
if let name = nodeTapped.name{
    print("An SCNNode Named \(name) Has Been Tapped")
}
```

Additionally, if you ONLY want to detect objects you have added e.g `SCNNodes` then you can simply remove part two of the getureRecognizer function.

Hope it helps...

Comment: @JoshRobins, Thanks a lot. A combination of the HitTests and node names did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you should loop through your scene nodes, after that you can manipulate with your wanted node. Example:

```
    for node in sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes {
            if node.name == "yorNodeName" {
               // do your manipulations
            }
        }
```

Don't forget to add name to your nodes. Example:

```
node.name = "yorNodeName"
```

I hope it helped!